Apply row uniqe identifier to all id content columns
I'm trying to figure out a way to assign a uniqe identifier to each row but keep the ids unique identifer the same as each row.
for first row:
id=row1, id=addbtn1, id=comment1
for second row:
id=row2, id=addbtn2, id=comment2, id=formAttachment2
for third row:
id=row3, id=addbtn3, id=comment3, id=formAttachment3

<div class="row" id="row" name="row">

    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <div id="AddButton">
            <br /><button name="addbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-link addbtn" style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: -40px" id="addbtn"><font color="green"><b>+ Add</b></font></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" cols="75" name="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row" name="row">

    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <div id="AddButton">
            <br /><button name="addbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-link addbtn" style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: -40px" id="addbtn"><font color="green"><b>+ Add</b></font></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" cols="75" name="comment"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="formAttachment" style="width: 500px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="row" name="row">

    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <div id="AddButton">
            <br /><button name="addbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-link addbtn" style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: -40px" id="addbtn"><font color="green"><b>+ Add</b></font></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" cols="75" name="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto" id="col">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="formAttachment" style="width: 500px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var addrow = 0;
        $("[name='row']").each(function () {
            addrow = addrow + 1;
            $(this).attr("id", "row" + addrow);
        });
    });
</script>

i tried manipulating the script each function but have not had any luck yet.

id is supposed to be unique for elements in a document. You have several elements with the same id name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

How does this code not meet your expectations? At this point it only attempts to set ids on the elements where name = "row", but nothing else.

FYI: Java and JavaScript are unrelated.

this issue is in the second row......if i use the same logic for id=formAttachment it would be id=formAttachment1 and id=row2.....since the first row does not have a formAttachment. I need the second row equal to formAttachment2

I'd iterate through the rows as you are, but then check each row for formAttachment, comment, addBtn, etc and re-identify them if they exist.

IDs might not be necessary at all if you ask me. This seems like an XY-Problem where you think you need X to achieve Y. Explain why do you think you need unique IDs in the first place - and what is that you're building and the desired goal.

Thank you @mykaf you pointed me in the right direction, the following works.
$(document).ready(function () {
  var addrow = 0;
  $("[name='row']").each(function () {
    addrow = addrow + 1;
    $(this).attr("id", "row" + addrow);
    $(this).find("#formAttachment").attr("id", "formAttachment" + addrow);
  });
});


First we are getting var $currentRow with  $("[name='row']").
Then in each row e.i $currentRow (which is an element of <div>)
we are getting addbtn, comment and formAttachemt with id. In case of first $currentRow the formAttachment is not present it won't do anything for this. for second time in the row it will find the formAttachment and will add current updated number.
please check and if it fulfills your requirements.
$(document).ready(function() {
        var addrow = 0;
        $("[name='row']").each(function() {
        addrow = addrow + 1;
        var $currentRow = $(this); 
        $currentRow.attr('id',"row_"+addrow);
        $currentRow.find("[id^='addbtn']").each(function() {
            var $element = $(this); 
            $element.attr('id', "addbtn_" + addrow);
        });

        $currentRow.find("[id^='comment']").each(function() {
            var $element = $(this); 
            $element.attr('id', "comment_" + addrow);
        });

        $currentRow.find("[id^='formAttachment']").each(function() {
            var $element = $(this); 
            $element.attr('id', "formAttachment_" + addrow);
        });
    });
});

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row" id="row" name="row">

        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <div id="AddButton">
                <br /><button name="addbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-link addbtn" style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: -40px" id="addbtn"><font color="green"><b>+ Add</b></font></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" cols="75" name="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="row" name="row">

        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <div id="AddButton">
                <br /><button name="addbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-link addbtn" style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: -40px" id="addbtn"><font color="green"><b>+ Add</b></font></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" cols="75" name="comment"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="formAttachment" style="width: 500px" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="row" name="row">

        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <div id="AddButton">
                <br /><button name="addbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-link addbtn" style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: -40px" id="addbtn"><font color="green"><b>+ Add</b></font></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" id="comment" cols="75" name="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto" id="col">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="formAttachment" style="width: 500px" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>





@Donnie if this code has worked for you please upvote and accept the answer as this will help the fellow devs to quickly find the right answer for right question.

as you can see in this example when i add another id tag for formAttachment it puts a uniqe identifer in id = row2 as id= formAttachment1 i need it to be id=formAttachment2 for id=row2 if that makes sense

Not sure how this id=formAttachment is getting changed, as there is no attribute called name on this field., you either need to add name attribute for formAttachment field or go with id's as above solution.

the above example is missing the formAttachment             var $cmt = $("#formAttachment");
$cmt.attr("id", "formAttachment_" + addrow);

run that and you can see how the id's get misaligned

Multiple IDs (id="row") is invalid in a single HTML page. Also, you might not need IDs at all.

@Roko C. Buljan Agree..
Donnie, if the updated answer is working for you, then please accept the answer, it will save time for fellow devs to land on right asnwer.
